# Translate $\sf CKKCpqCqrpr$ into classical notation

Tags: logic, polish-notation

From polish to classical notation

$\sf CKKCpqCqrpr$

I have $((p\to q)\land(q\to r)\land p)\to r~
$ for "$\sf CpqCqrpr
$" but I don't understand what $\sf CKK$ means in the beginning.

Comment: "I have (p->q)^((q->r)^p)->r for "CpqCqrpr"" How exactly do you have that? $CpqCqrpr$ isn't a well-formed formula on its own: each of the four pieces "$Cpq$," "$Cqr$," "$p$," and "$r$" is a well-formed formula, but just putting them next to each other doesn't do anything meaningful (we need to *connect* them - e.g. with $C$s and $K$s!).

Comment: It might help to consider a simpler example: can you figure out what "$CCpqr$" translates to?

Comment: i believe that would be ((p->q)^r) , i just don't understand how to imply the first C? I know Cpq is (p->q) itself

Comment: It might be helpful to add parantheses; so, in @NoahSchweber's example, we can group the terms as $C(Cpq)r.$ Then does it make sense why this translates to $(p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow r$?

Comment: (also, as a tip, use "\wedge" to get the conjunction symbol in mathjax, rather than a carat. so for instance $p\wedge q$ is obtained by the code "p\wedge q". also, use "\rightarrow" to get $\rightarrow$)

Comment: or `\land` if you like.

Comment: The simplest way to "decode" it is to restore parentheses, recalling that [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) is a prefixed notation and knowing that the propositional connectives are binary except $\mathsf N$ (negation) which is unary.

Comment: Thus, starting from the inner conditionals ($\mathsf C$): $CKK(Cpq)(Cqr)pr$. Now we have to apply conjunctions ($\mathsf K$):  $CK(K((Cpq)(Cqr))p)r$. Finally there is the outermost conditional: $C(K(K((Cpq)(Cqr))p)r)$.

Answer (score 3):

No, the string of $\sf CpqCqrpr$ is not a well formed formulae .

---

A string of the form $\sf CKKabcd$ translates to $\sf((a\land b)\land c)\to d$, as follows:

$$\sf{CKKabcd\\CK(a{\land}b)cd\\C((a{\land}b){\land}c)d\\((a{\land}b){\land}c){\to}d}$$

---

So it is the *entire statement* of $\sf CKKCpqCqrpr$ that translates as $((p\to q)\land(q\to r)\land p)\to r~$ as follows:$$\sf{CKKCpqCqrpr\\CKK(p{\to}q)(q{\to}r)pr\\(((p{\to}q){\land}(q{\to}r)){\land}p){\to}r}$$

Answer (score 2):

Graham Kemp has already explained how to translate the specific example you're looking at; let me try to address what I think is the source of your confusion.

I think the issue is with how you're interpreting **concatenation** - it sounds like you think concatenation is how we write *conjunction* in Polish notation, so that e.g. "$Cpqr$" means "$(p\rightarrow q)\wedge r$." This is not the case. Conjunction is denoted by "$K$" which behaves syntactically just like "$C$" does, so "$(p\rightarrow q)\wedge r$" in Polish notation would be written "$KCpqr$."

So what *does* concatenation mean? The answer is:

> Nothing whatsoever!

An expression like "$Cpqr$" is **not meaningful**: it has two *maximal well-formed components*, namely "$Cpq$" and "$r$," but the whole thing isn't a complete expression yet. Similarly, the expression "$CpqCqrpr$" you consider in the OP is not meaningful on its own: it's just four well-formed formulas put next to each other, namely "$Cpq$," "$Cqr$," "$p$," and "$r$." Additional connectives are needed to combine these into a single expression, and this is exactly what the "$CKK$" at the front is doing.

Comment: I think the OP's confusion is not exactly what you inferred. Note that the attempted translation of $CpqCqrpr$ has three implication symbols, even though there are only two $C$'s. Systematically reading conjunctions as $\land$ would have produced $\land$ rather than $\to$ before the final $r$.  I must admit, though, that I can't think of any systematic confusion that would actually produce what the OP wrote.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So what I actually think happened is that they both made the mistake I suggest *and* misread the sentence in question. I focused my answer around my best guess at the substantive mistake being made, but you're right I could easily be wrong.